# Swift - constraint animation - incorrect subviews animating

Tags: ios, animation, uiview, autolayout

I have extended UIView:

```
class A: UIView {
     private var _height: NSLayoutConstraint!
     private var _centerLabel: UILabel = {
        let lb = UILabel()
        lb.text = "Some text"
        lb.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        lb.textAlignment = .center
        lb.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return lb
    }()

     func open() {
          self._height.constant = 50
          self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
     }

     func close() {
         UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 1, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
                self._height.constant = 0
                self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
            }, completion: nil)
     }

     override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.addSubview(_centerLabel)

        _height = self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            _centerLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            _centerLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            _centerLabel.topAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 16),
            _centerLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -16),
            _height
        ])
    }
}
```

MainViewController:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var a: A!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
   }

   @IBAction func open(_ sender: Any) {
       a.open()
   }

   @IBAction func close(_ sender: Any) {
       a.close()
   }

}
```

If I call `close()`, instance of UIView A animates correctly, all other constraint attached to it as well. However, content of A (`_centerLabel`) disappears immediatelly, its height is not animated at all. Why?

Comment: Where are you calling close method? Please show the code

Comment: @user1000 I have added main view controller code. There are constraints, buttons and other subview added in storyboard.

Comment: call `self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()` before your animation block

Comment: @ReinierMelian Tried, but the same result.

Comment: @MartinPerry you are trying to colapse your view?

Comment: @ReinierMelian Yes

Comment: @MartinPerry I will setup your code in one example to see what is going on I need you answer me  this two questions, What animation you need to do your Label? and your label is inside of your view?

Comment: @ReinierMelian Label should animate its height together with UIView A. Label is inside UIView, as `self.addSubview(_centerLabel)`